# Lower the 'Deployment Target' to see older simulators or check your Apple SDK path warning after update

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I updated my XCode to XCode 13 for make test my Xamarin.iOS app on ios 15 devices. I updated visual studio for mac app to version 8.10.9
After this updating, I opened my app in visual studio for mac but when I try to choose devices, I can't see devices. There is only a message that: "Lower the 'Deployment Target' to see older simulators or check your Apple SDK path"

I tried to change deployment target and I checked Apple SDK path from Preferences/SDK Locations/Apple/Apple SDK. I tried to set path both "/Applications/Xcode.app" and "/Applications/Xcode.app/". But none of them didn't worked for me. What sould I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a Xcode 13 compatible version of Visual Studio for Mac/Xamarin.iOS released yet. It should be here soon, but if you need it to work now, go over to the Apple Developer portal and download the latest Xcode 12 version and (re)install that.

More information can be found [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/12778).

Comment: Thanks for reply. When will release compatible version of Visual Studio for Mac/Xamarin.iOS with XCode 13? Do you know?

Comment: Often a good idea to wait updating Xcode until an update in Visual Studio addressing the Xcode update is available.

Answer (score 4):

Just experienced the same issue after auto update to Xcode 14. **Downgrading to Xcode 13.4.1** fixed the issue.

More information about Xamarin.iOS support with Xcode 14 [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15954)

Comment: Didn't work for me? Just uninstalled 14 and downloaded and installed 13.4.1. Restarted my mac and visual studio still the same, did I miss something?

Comment: Got it, had to update the apple sdk location

Answer (score 2):

**Works well on Visual Studio for Mac 17.5.4 (build 8) and macOS Ventura 13.3.1(a)**

> Follow all these simple and straightforward steps.

Download Xcode 13 release, 13.4.1 from [here](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13.4.1/Xcode_13.4.1.xip).

**Extract** the contents of the *.xip* file. It will be named **Xcode.app**. Since you already have an **Xcode.app** in the Applications folder, you’ll need to rename it. Preference is to name it with version. In this case, `Xcode13_4_1.app`. Then drag it to the Applications folder.

And then make it the default Xcode. From a shell, run the following

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode13_4_1.app
```

To verify that this is now the current version of Xcode, run the following

```
sudo xcode-select -p
```

That should come back with something like

```
/Applications/Xcode13_4_1.app/Contents/Developer
```

After doing that, I restarted Visual Studio and enjoy the simulators back

[image]

To switch back to latest version, just run `xcode-select` again

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
For I am using VS with ISO 16.4 and Xcode 14.3. If you perform the steps and switch back to the latest version the devices stay available.
And for completeness last comment is 
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error in Oct 2022 with XCode 13.3.1 installed on an M1 Air with Monterey macOS 12.3.1.

Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac, Version 17.3.5 (build 0)

This is a project several years old that I've not worked on for over a year. The deployment target in the info.plist is 9.3.

I have no problems building a new Xamarin Forms project and running on the simulator.

The SDK Locations panel says:

*XCode 13.3.1 found at the system location (xcode-select)*

`/Applications/Xcode.app`

After satisfying myself that a basic new project worked, I applied the simple classic technique of deleting the `obj` and `bin` folders for the core and iOS projects. That fixed it and I was able to build and run on the simulator.